# line power detection in video

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a small project "Detect the electric wire on the train" using Matlab.

[image]. The wire I circled in red is the one i need to detect.

I tried egde detection but don't know what to do next. Can anyone suggest any ways to do this ? Here is the link of the [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3j4or1dxxv3fmt/Eric_Video.avi?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Hough Transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/hough-transform.html) for line detection.

Most of my post is based on Hough Transform documentation.

Sample code:

```
%Read input image from imgur
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcHfy.png');

J = zeros(size(I,1), size(I,2));

%Select dark pixels (assume wires are dark).
J((I(:,:,1) < 80) & (I(:,:,2) < 80) & (I(:,:,3) < 80)) = 1;

%figure;imshow(J);

%Find the edges in the image using the edge function.
BW = edge(J,'canny');
%figure;imshow(BW);


%Compute the Hough transform of the binary image returned by edge.
[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW);

%Display the transform, H, returned by the hough function.
% figure;imshow(imadjust(mat2gray(H)),[], 'XData',theta, 'YData',rho, 'InitialMagnification','fit');
% xlabel('\theta (degrees)');ylabel('\rho');axis on;axis normal ;hold on;colormap(gca,hot);

%Find the peaks in the Hough transform matrix, H, using the houghpeaks function.
P = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));

%Superimpose a plot on the image of the transform that identifies the peaks.
%x = theta(P(:,2));y = rho(P(:,1));plot(x,y,'s','color','black');

%Find lines in the image using the houghlines function.
lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',50,'MinLength',7);

%Create a plot that displays the original image with the lines superimposed on it.
figure, imshow(I), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
```

Result:
[image]

Remarks:
You may improve the results using **morphological** operations.
Modify my code "Selecting dark pixels (assume wires are dark)".
Change Hough Transform parameters.

Comment: Thanks Rotem, your example worked perfect for single frame. However, I tried to apply it for the whole [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3j4or1dxxv3fmt/Eric_Video.avi?dl=0). I tried to used implay but still cannot do it. Can you help me ?

Comment: You can use `VideoReader`: [https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-object.html](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-object.html), for reading the video frame by frame. Executing line detection for each frame separately is not the best approach, but it's a good start.